# how to use pandas dataframe after splitting my test set?

Tags: python, validation, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

i have recently learned how to do validation split on my pandas dataframe , but after spliting i noticed that i am not able to slice my columns .

```
print(my_data['column name'])
```

it throwing an error , please help .

my code goes like this :

```
import pandas as pd  
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
data = pd.read_csv("labeledTrainData.tsv" , header = 0 ,  \
           delimiter = '\t' , quoting  = 3)

train  , test = train_test_split(data , train_size = 0.8 , random_state = 38)
print(len(train['sentiment']))
```

please tell me whether this problem is faced in numpy too?

Comment: What version of Sklearn you are using, the behaviour changed in a recent version so that it returns the same type as the inputs, so in principle it should've worked but if you're using an older version then you get just the indices

Comment: i am using a very recent version

Comment: btw in `sci-kit 0.18` the module `cross validation` was deprecated in favour of `model_selection` !

Answer (score 4):

[`train_test_split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html) returns a list of the splits, you're supposed to use these to index the df:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =train_test_split(data , train_size = 0.8 , random_state = 38)
```

then you index like so:

```
data.iloc[X_train]
data.iloc[X_test]
data.iloc[y_train]
data.iloc[y_test]
```

Answer (score 0):

If we input simple numpy arrays the output are numpy arrays too. See an example [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html) :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
>>> X, y = np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2)), range(5)
>>> X
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])
>>> list(y)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
>>> X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
...     X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
...
>>> X_train
array([[4, 5],
       [0, 1],
       [6, 7]])
>>> y_train
[2, 0, 3]
>>> X_test
array([[2, 3],
       [8, 9]])
>>> y_test
[1, 4]
```

## EDIT

I tried the same thing but i did not get any errors, I am using Python 2.7+. So is this something specific to different version of Python or Scikitlearn

```
    import pandas as pd  
    from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
    url = 'https://raw.github.com/pydata/pandas/master/pandas/tests/data/tips.csv'
    data = pd.read_csv(url)

    train  , test = train_test_split(data ,train_size = 0.8 , random_state = 38)
    print (train['total_bill'])
Output:
....
211    25.89
53      9.94
75     10.51
161    12.66
Name: total_bill, dtype: float64
```

Comment: btw in `sci-kit 0.18` the module `cross validation` was deprecated in favour of `model_selection` !